# Magento won't show all products on homepage

Tags: magento, product

I am having problems displaying all products on my magento homepage. I have added this code to my CMS - pages - design:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list"
        name="home.catalog.product.list"
        alias="products_homepage"
        template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

but had no luck. I have tried re-indexing my products and I have flushed the cache. Been at this for hours now looking for answers.

I have also tried adding the category id to the above code.

I have a custom theme on my Magento so maybe it has something to do with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to your CMS page CONTENT, not design.

Comment: you are a LEGEND!!! After 2 days of messing around with all sorts of setting it was somthing as little as this! i am a complete tool!

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a fresh set of eyes :)  We've all been there.

Comment: seriously thanks man! i am still made uo about this haha. i posted this on the magento forums as well but nobody ever gets back to me. i think that forum is dead :( stackoverflow is the place to go!